# favicon - all new browsers request favicon while loading page?

Tags: browser, favicon

All new browsers & mobile browsers make additional request to `favicon.ico` while loading page?

And from what version of Internet Explorer/Firefox, this browsers start to request `favicon.ico`?

They do it only on first page load or on every page load?

When request to `favicon.ico` take place: a) while page loading b) after page loaded c) before loading page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. All major browser support favicon.ico. You could use a link tag for the best results:

   `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://example.com/myicon.ico" />`
2. It started with IE5. Firefox was not released for about 5 years afterward, but version 1.0 supported favicon.ico also.
3. The request order of `favicon.ico` can be specified by using the `<link>` tag. You can verify the order of the request by using Firebug in Firefox or the Web Inspector in Safari or Chrome.

More information on Wikipedia: [Favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmark_icon)

Answer (score 0):

The above answer by woz is true. But, now `"shortcut icon"` has been deprecated and one can simply use `"icon"` as follows:

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```

It is not compulsory to use `.ico` images, either. All the latest browsers support PNG favicons. You can render them using following:

```
<link href="favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/png" />
```

Sometimes, browsers behave in a weird fashion. If you just interchange the order of the `rel` and the `href` attributes in the `link` tag, the browser renders the favicon. This happened to me in a real time hosted project.